# Filename regex not working with caret ^ character

Tags: c#, regex

I know I have probably overlooked something, but have looked online and can't seem to find the answer... I am running a regex expression on a bunch of file names to remove delete ones I don't need. This is my code (in windows forms):

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(fileName, EditBox_Filters.Text))
    Remove = true;
```

This seems to work fine in certain circumstances, like this:

```
007.*\[!\]
```

Is picking up these two files:

```
007 Shitou (J) [!].gen
James Bond 007 - The Duel (UE) [!].gen
```

Yet, if I wanted to get only the file that started with 007 I would think I could use:

```
^007
```

But when I use the ^ character the regex keeps returning false, is this something to do with the string itself.. or am I just delusional?

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe there's an issue with your file names, so that they don't *really* start with `007`? Invisible unicode characters are one way the names might be "malformed".

Comment: You do not need a regex to check if a string starts with `007`. Use `if (fileName.StartsWith("007"))`. Yes, and use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)` to only check the file names without the folder path and extensions (thus, you can get rid of regexes for most cases).

Comment: Since you are handling file names. Make sure you really compare the _file_name and not the complete path (which most likely doesn't start with 007).

Comment: I do need a regular expression because the regex is user input, so I can re-use this program again in the future. But oh my goodness, thanks Christian I had forgotten to get the last part of the file name before displaying it to the screen. It was a late night lol! Thank you and I'll just walk away embarrassed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure only the file *name* **without the folder path and extension** is tested against the regex, use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), EditBox_Filters.Text))
    Remove = true;
```

Comment: As Christian K said, this was the problem.. that I was looking at the entire filename + path. This post was also helpful because I was manually extracting the last part of the path before :)